NoClassDefFoundError exception after updating to the latest maven-surefire-plugin and latest junit5
I've got the following issue while I've been trying to use latest version of the JUnit5 (5.10.3) and latest version of the maven-surefire-plugin (3.3.0).
Caused by: org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooterForkException: There was an error in the forked process
org/apache/maven/surefire/report/RunModeSetter
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/maven/surefire/report/RunModeSetter
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:756)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:473)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:74)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:369)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:363)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:352)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformProvider.invoke(JUnitPlatformProvider.java:113)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:385)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.execute(ForkedBooter.java:162)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.run(ForkedBooter.java:507)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:495)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.maven.surefire.report.RunModeSetter
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:387)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:352)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
        ... 17 more

I've followed most of the official instructions (both junit and maven surefire) but nothing seems helping in my case.
The only difference is that the issue disappear if I go back to maven-surefire-plugin with version 3.0.0-M3
Are there any ways to found is it something known and already in-fix or what would be done differently on my end?
It is a bit confusing that according to the maven surefire documentation everything should work.
p.s. I'm using JUnit5 as a bom and tried different combination of corresponding dependencies, like both engine and api or just api
p.p.s. As for the maven version:
$ mvn -version
Apache Maven 3.9.0 (9b58d2bad23a66be161c4664ef21ce219c2c8584)
Maven home: C:\Users\mlaptev\Downloads\apache-maven-3.9.0
Java version: 1.8.0_412, vendor: Temurin, runtime: C:\Program Files\Eclipse Adoptium\jdk-8.0.412.8-hotspot\jre
Default locale: en_GB, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 10", version: "10.0", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"



[edit] the question and add a [mre]. Include version of Maven and the pom.xml.

Please post your pom file...

that's something that I'm trying to extract, since due to obvious reasons, I cannot post the pom.xml as is

In my case i had to remove junit-platform-surefire-provider:
<!--        <dependency>-->
<!--            <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>-->
<!--            <artifactId>junit-platform-surefire-provider</artifactId>-->
<!--            <version>1.3.2</version>-->
<!--            <scope>test</scope>-->
<!--        </dependency>-->

And exception 'Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.maven.surefire.report.RunModeSetter' has gone.
I tested combination of surefire 3.4.0 and junit jupiter 5.10.3.

Thanks, Simon. Interesting observation! Let me cross-check if there's something similar in our code

Try updating your jdk to 17 or any latest version

That is not related...

1. Update below POM Configuration in the "pom.xml"
    <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
        <version>5.10.3</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
        <version>5.10.3</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <useModulePath>false</useModulePath>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

2. then force update dependencies by using
mvn clean install -U


that didn't help unfortunately.
it is probably something messy in the setup we are having, continue to look into it.
but, meanwhile, when with everything working on 3.0.0-M3, switching to 3.0.0-M4 lead to issue that is similar to https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SUREFIRE-1951 and after adding workaround as it has been mentioned in the jira, the originally posted issue has happen after switching from 3.0.0-M5 to 3.0.0-M6.
will continue looking into the smallest project that can be used as reproducer

Actually, it seems gone with using surefire plugin version 3.4.0

In my case adding
<dependency>
     <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
     <artifactId>common-java5</artifactId>
     <version>${maven-surefire-plugin.version}</version>
     <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>

helped avoiding this error
Update:
After some investigation I found out that this dependency was breaking Surefire classpath and I had to add an exclusion.

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.psambit9791</groupId>
    <artifactId>jdsp</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-platform-surefire-provider</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency> 

Also raised this JIRA
https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/SUREFIRE/issues/SUREFIRE-2285

Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?
